# MSVC environment variables in git bash using ConEmu

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, git-bash, conemu

I'm trying to start git bash with environment variables from vcvarsall.bat using ConEmu.

Currently my startup task is just `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\vc14.bat"`.
The bat file looks as following:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cls
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

The problem is that when I close ConEmu I get this message

[image]

Is there any way to do what my bat file is doing from ConEmu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` because `Git\bin\sh.exe` is just a wrapper.
2. You should run `sh.exe` asynchronously, because when you run it from cmd's batch, `cmd.exe` waits for for `sh.exe` completion, and ConEmu sees the `cmd.exe` in the console process, which rises "Incomplete operations" warning.

---

Correct batch:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cls
ConEmuC -async -c "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```